# How to find where an object first instantiatiation

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, theme-options

> Problem is solved.

I have built a theme options class so i can build as many option pages as i want, an i implement a singleton design pattern to fetch options only once, and i have WPML plugin installed so i am trying to make options multilingual using the available hook `wpml_multilingual_options` and every thing seems to be saved and also displayed correctly on frontend but unfortunately in the admin it keeps showing the none translated options, so i am guessing that the singleton object is called somehow before the `init` hook where the `wpml_multilingual_options` is hooked to. But i can't find where exactly that singleton object is. can i track an object of the same singleton to find out the path of where the first instantiation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out how to track the object, by using the `debug_print_backtrace()` within the constructor, and now my issue has been solved